# Regex, preg_match, returns too many results?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My code is working well enough -- but I don't understand the results. My goal is to make sure that the value passed in is in one of these formats:

- 00000-0000
- 000000000
- 00000

PHP:

```
$str = '12345-6789';
preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}(-?[0-9]{4})?$/', $str, $found);
print_r($found);
```

Return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345-6789
    [1] => -6789
)
```

Why am I getting the second result, `[1] => -6789`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses around `(-?...` cause it to be captured.  The zeroth entry of `$found` contains the whole match and each subsequent entry contains each captured group.  This is probably fine, but if you absolutely do not want to capture, you can use a non-capture group:

```
(?:-?[0-9]{4})?
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it. Kinda like Apache backreferences.

Comment: @jared_flack they're not specific to apache.  A backreference is a reference to a captured group in the same expression (e.g. `(\d)\1` -- the `\1` is a backreference to the captured digit).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have a capturing group as you used `(` and `)`'s:

```
$str = '12345-6789';
preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}(-?[0-9]{4})?$/', $str, $found);
//                    ^          ^
print_r($found);
```

You can use `?:` to make sure it is non capturing:

```
$str = '12345-6789';
preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}(?:-?[0-9]{4})?$/', $str, $found);
//                     ^^
print_r($found);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-` was inside of the `()` that's called `capture block`, these blocks are the matches that PHP will return.

```
$str = '12345-6789';
preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}-?([0-9]{4})?$/', $str, $found);
print_r($found);
```